# How do I spin my shovel?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Ive seen people who do Let's Plays of this game on YouTube do this cool shovel spinning thing in their digging action. Ive tried pressing different buttons to try to do this, but nothing works. How do I do it?

Comment: Could you post a link to the video?

Answer (score 4):

The spinning of the shovel happens when you are in a multi-player session. It occurs because it takes time to log hole data on the other player's town, So the spin happens to account for that time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's cool that they turned a delay into an actually fun animation =D Too bad there's no equivalent with picking up things, there you just see the delay...